# Election page is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, notifications

I just got a notification telling me to vote in the election.

When following the link however, I'm redirected to [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/election) (an error page). Presumably, this is supposed to be the election page.

---

It seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Already pinged a CM. Let's hope this gets resolved soon.

Comment: I [blame the lack of a ployglot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363224/bring-back-the-404-polyglot)

Comment: @Dennis Ya. The last thing we need is people moving on and forgetting to vote, which I totally won't do. A new notification might not hurt.

Comment: The entire election page is bust https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election should display past elections if the current one isn't runing. On the other hand I just got a badge for looking at the non-existent page.

Comment: So there _is_ no correct link? The title made me think that this post is just about the notification.

Comment: I've been to two other SEs and `/election` works just fine for them (I get a normal page saying there's no election). PCG's page still throws a 500

Comment: @Machavity [Crypto has the same problem.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/election)

Comment: @Dennis Weird. [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election) and [Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/election) work

Comment: @Machavity Crypto has an ongoing election.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I updated the wording of the question to reflect new information.

Comment: [This has been posted to Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306914/296259) and it turns out cooking.SE has a working election page in nomination phase (PPCG and Crypto are in Election phase, Crypto has been for 7 days).

Comment: This is bad. Really bad. Elections are supposed to follow rules that were established before. Things like that hurt the legitimization of the result, because the result might be different if people could have voted.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Well, I'm hoping this will be taken into consideration. That's why I'm hoping they send another alert when it's fixed to remind people, and perhaps extend the time to vote if this takes a long time to fix.

Comment: Appears to be working now

Comment: And because of this issue...I forgot to vote